# losing styles after jquery .css() and .animate()

Tags: jquery

After my animations I loose these css styles. Is there a way I can add them back using something like .()append? and not `$(this).removeAttr('style');`

```
.grid li a:hover img {

-webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
-moz-transition: opactiy .3s ease-in;
-ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
-o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
opacity: 1;
}

.grid:hover li {   
 -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opactiy .3s ease-in;
 -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
 -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
 transition: opacity .3s ease-in;   
 zoom: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=1);
 opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Here is the code that's doing the animations

```
  $('#container img').addClass("img_org");
    $(this).siblings().css("top", "0px");
     $(this).siblings().stop();
    $(this).parent().detach();       
    $('.pop_title').css({ "margin-left": "25%", "margin-right": "25%", top: "100px", left: "0", "font-size": "200%"});      
    $('#container').css({ left: image.left, top: image.top, opacity: 1})
                   .animate({marginLeft: '25%',marginRight: '25%', top: '150', left: '0'},200,'easeInCubic', function(){

       $('.nextButton, .prevButton, .zoom_back, .zoom_big, .info, .box_counter ').animate({opacity: 1},500);            
       $('.pop_title').css("font-size", "200%").text(content.navgrid[2][location].title);
            });           

    $('#container ul, #container').css({height: "422px",width: "679px"});
```

Comment: `removeAttr('style')` may "lose" them, yes; in general that is likely an inadvisable approach. Where is the *code*?

Comment: Keep attributes in class and add back the class after animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about your animate method removing inline CSS you should choose a different approach.
Try just adding an original class:

```
.exampleClass
{
    height:50px;
}
```

Create a div of that class:

```
<div class="exampleClass"></div>
```

Animate it:

```
$('.exampleClass').animate({height:'100px'}, 200);
```

And remove the inline styles to revert back to your original CSS:

```
$('.exampleClass').removeAttr('style');
```

And you'll preserve your original CSS since it's still the stylesheet.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yzTRK/)

Comment: Is there anyway I can just addStyle() and not .removeAttr('style'); because it doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. When you want to add styles to an element there are two ways of doing it. 1) From the Stylesheet 2) Inline CSS which is the style attribute inside of the element. For example: `<div style="height:50px"></div>` -- this is inline CSS. You can remove the style attribute, thereby removing your inline CSS. Only your stylesheet CSS will remain at this point.